# Fix google map marker in center

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

In my flutter app. I am using `google_maps_plugin` . The link is https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter .
I want to fix the marker in center of map without movable after draging the map. 
I want it likes http://jsfiddle.net/UuDA6/
In my code i am using `MarkerOption` for placing the marker.

```
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions(   
        alpha: 1.0,
        anchor: Offset(0.5, 1.0),
        consumeTapEvents: false,
        draggable: false,
        flat: false,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        infoWindowAnchor: Offset(0.5, 0.0),
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText.noText,
        position: LatLng(17.411439, 78.5486697),
        rotation: 0.0,
        visible: true,
        zIndex: 0.0,
    );
```

But in the `position` i want to know how to give the center of map.

If any one have idea about it please share it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually with new update of [google_maps_flutter: ^0.4.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#040) we can achieve above requirement easily.

This is the demo [link](https://youtu.be/RxPAuIgr6QA).

```
Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
int _markerIdCounter = 0;
Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();

Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: GoogleMap(
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: Constants.LOCATION_SRI_LANKA,
        zoom: 12.0,
      ),
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
        if(_markers.length > 0) {
          MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(_markerIdVal());
          Marker marker = _markers[markerId];
          Marker updatedMarker = marker.copyWith(
            positionParam: position.target,
          );

          setState(() {
            _markers[markerId] = updatedMarker;
          });
        }
      },
    ),
  )

void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
  _mapController.complete(controller);
  if ([INITIAL_LOCATION] != null) {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(_markerIdVal());
    LatLng position = [INITIAL_LOCATION];
    Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: position,
      draggable: false,
    );
    setState(() {
      _markers[markerId] = marker;
    });

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
      controller.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
            target: position,
            zoom: 17.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

String _markerIdVal({bool increment = false}) {
  String val = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
  if (increment) _markerIdCounter++;
  return val;
}
```

Comment: what is INITIAL_LOCATION here ?

Comment: @JonStark when the app launches for the first time, the map will start from INITIAL_LOCATION and then continue with user location updates.

Comment: @PasanRandulaEramusugoda nice solution, but what is the feature in `google_maps_flutter: ^0.4.0`  which let put the marker in the center of google map

Comment: @PasanRandulaEramusugoda Great solution.
Adding on to your solution which may create jerks in the marker, we can update the _markers[] list with the updatedMarker inside the onMapIdle() function and update the state there.

Answer (score 16):

The right answer is to use `Stack` and overlay marker pin on map. if you try to put marker on map using GoogleMaps markers property, you have to update marker position on `CameraMove` and call `setState` which add latency on redrawing maker.

compare two approaches:

[image]

```
class StoreLocationMap extends StatefulWidget {
  final Coordinate userLocation;
  const StoreLocationMap({Key? key, required this.userLocation})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StoreLocationMapState createState() => _StoreLocationMapState();
}

class _StoreLocationMapState extends State<StoreLocationMap> {
  final List<Marker> _markers = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(
                  widget.userLocation.latitude, widget.userLocation.longitude),
              zoom: 14),

        
          markers: _markers.toSet(),
        
          onMapCreated: (controller) {
            final marker = Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('0'),
              position: LatLng(
                  widget.userLocation.latitude, widget.userLocation.longitude),
              
            );

            _markers.add(marker);
          },
          onCameraMove: (position) {
            setState(() {
              _markers.first =
                  _markers.first.copyWith(positionParam: position.target);
            });
          },
        ),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/delivery-area-start-pin.png',
          frameBuilder: (context, child, frame, wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
            return Transform.translate(
              offset: const Offset(8, -37),
              child: child,
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As my custom marker has shadow and is not symmetric, I used `Transform` widget to translate custom marker to point to right location.

**How to get map center coordinate? or center maker position?**

User `onCameraMove` to get map center position:

```dart
onCameraMove: (position) {
            print(position.target);
          },
```

Answer (score 13):

This is based on the @Joe answer but it has more accurated pin position and no other class is required:

```
double mapWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double mapHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 215;
double iconSize = 40.0;

return new Stack(
    alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        width: mapWidth,
        height: mapHeight,
        child: _googleMap
      ),
      new Positioned(
        top: (mapHeight - iconSize)/ 2,
        right: (mapWidth - iconSize)/ 2,
        child: new Icon(Icons.person_pin_circle, size: iconSize),
      )
  ]);
```

This solution don't require to repaint the entire Screen (no setState call) when user update the position. You won't see that weird marker "movement".

Comment: It's not the corrent place show. `(mapHeight - 100)/ 2,` now it's correct place

Comment: The center is a bit off for me with this solution. Align center as per Joe's answer works fine.

Comment: How to know the coordinates for the marker then?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible using stack. The code is shown below.

```
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
GoogleMap(
onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
),
InfoView()                  
 ],)
```

The InfoView is

```
class InfoView extends State<AppPage> {
    const InfoView({
        Key key,
        })  : super(key: key);

   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: new Icon(Icons.person_pin_circle, size: 40.0),

        );
    }
}
```

Then the _onMapCreated is

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
        setState(() {
        mapController = controller;
            mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                    CameraPosition(
                    bearing: 270.0,
                    target: LatLng(lattitude, longitude),
                    tilt: 30.0,
                    zoom: 17.0,
                    ),
                ));
        });
    }
    }
```

This stack class is useful if you want to overlap several children in a simple way, for example having some text and an image, overlaid with a gradient and a button attached to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to you to try this new Flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker

Answer (score 2):

Use Stack and IgnorePointer to ignore touches on your widget

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      ....
    ),
    Center(
     child: IgnorePointer(
       child: ...
     )
    )               
  ]
)
```