# How to add Animation for Google Maps Marker In Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-animation

Is there any way to animate marker on google maps in flutter like the native android ????

I'm using `google_maps_flutter`. It gives us a set of markers to set. But when am changing the coordinates of a marker it is simply being disappeared and appeared in the new place.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this??

Comment: Still, there is no option to animate more than one markers at the same time. But I have suggested a workaround for one maker with smooth animation.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55135087/4362756

Comment: @user9076720 Try this new package: Animaker https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker

Comment: https://youtu.be/Ch9GDrjSJs4 watch this

Answer (score 1):

Solution! https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker
It's works! You just need install one plugin.

Comment: Are you able to provide a code snippet please :)

Comment: this lib is not so good for real time product. it has many issues with the real animation.